# Hide status bar after calling imagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

No matter what I do, status bar keeps coming when i open image picker and won't go away after it is dismissed. I tried various swift solutions I was able to read on this site that are supposed to be fix the problem, but it won't help at all.

Here is what I do. I subclass the picker controller:

```
class MyImagePickerController: UIImagePickerController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.setNavBar()
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        self.setNavBar()
        return true
    }

    override func childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden() -> UIViewController? {
        return nil;
    }

    func setNavBar() -> Void {
        self.setNavBar(65)
    }


    func setNavBar(height: CGFloat) -> Void {
        var frame = self.navigationBar.frame;
        frame.size.height = height;
        self.navigationBar.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

then I to call it from an IBoutled action:

```
    func chooseImageFromGallery() {
    var image  = MyImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false
    self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Also, of course, I set the bar hidden in the Plist file. Problem is specifically when calling the picker controller.
Please answer in Swift.

Comment: Are you setting the 'view controller-based status bar appearance' key in the plist?

Comment: this bool should be set to NO right ? I have it set to NO

Comment: @RobertBrax, you have to set that to YES.

Comment: like @RobertBrax said it needs to be YES and then in the UIImagePicker subclass you need to explicitly hide the status bar

Comment: Got it, so the problem was that the view controler didn't had power to manage status bar. It all works fine, except that when the image picker controller shows up, on first screen I don't see the status bar, but it appears when I browse into a specific photo album. This is not a big deal, because when user has finished pick up his photo, it stays hidden, but maybe you know how to enforce hide even in the case where user browse his albums ?

Comment: you can post as answer and i'll chose it

Answer (score 3):

Use below code to do this

```
import Foundation

extension UIImagePickerController {
    override public func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

this is an extention(category) of **UIImagePickerController** and works for me.